# Benchmarking of USB flash drive

Tags: usb, benchmarks

I will appreciate if you can tell me some tools for ubuntu 14.04 LTS, that can measure transfer speed of USB flash drive. I need two or more programs to compare the results and if I can choose the size of the file that would be great.

Answer (score 37):

Use built-in program `disks` from ubuntu launcher, select your pendrive, click on gear icon, and select `benchmark` option to run read/write speed test

Comment: `apt install gnome-disk-utility`

Comment: In more recent versions, the option is called "**Benchmark Partition...**"

Answer (score 10):

I know it's a bit old of a post but! You could try the following:

`sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sd`

I've used this on multiple occasions with good success. Nice and easy. Not to mention built in.

You could also use the `dd` command:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=./largefile bs=8k count=10000`

I'd recommend reviewing the link below though for using the `dd` command for testing. This is what I've referenced before for testing with dd.

http://www.binarytides.com/linux-test-drive-speed/

It talks about how you have to adjust the `bs` option depending on the size of the USB you are testing.

Comment: If " hdparm: command not found", install it by run "apt update && apt install hdparm -y"

Comment: Ok i had `hdparm` installed stock, but it doesn't seem to be able to benchmark anything other than read, and for USB sticks *write* is the most important and deciding parameter.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I believe that's where the example of dd will prove useful and should also come stock on most distributions.